# Range to look for first $N$ prime numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

What range of numbers $[2, X]$ should I search, to be absolutely sure that I would get exactly or more than $N$ prime numbers within that range? Any formula for $X$?

Comment: [wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}$ by the PNT, $p_n$ behaves like $n\log n$. You may use Chebyshev's weak version $$C_1\frac{x}{\log x}\leq \pi(x)\leq C_2\frac{x}{\log x}$$
to deduce explicit (enough) bounds for $p_n$.

Anyway, unless $n$ is extremely small, there are at least $n$ primes in the range $[2,n\log^2(n)]$.

Answer (score 0):

Rosser and Schoenfeld proved that for $X \ge 17$ there are at least $N$ primes less than or equal to $\dfrac X {\ln X}$. So, choose $X$ so that $\dfrac X {\ln X} \ge N$.